# Assert type information onto computed results in Julia

Tags: julia

#### Problem

I read in an array of strings from a file.

```
julia> file = open("word-pairs.txt");
julia> lines = readlines(file);
```

But Julia doesn't know that they're strings.

```
julia> typeof(lines)
Array{Any,1}
```

#### Question

Can I tell Julia this somehow?

Is it possible to insert type information onto a computed result?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know the context where this is an issue, because there might be a better way to express what you need - or there could be a subtle bug somewhere.

> Can I tell Julia this somehow?

No, because the `readlines` function explicitly creates an `Any` array (`a = {}`): https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/io.jl#L230

> Is it possible to insert type information onto a computed result?

You can convert the array:

```
r = convert(Array{ASCIIString,1}, w)
```

Or, create your own `readstrings` function based on the link above, but using `ASCIIString[]` for the collection array instead of `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Isaiah is right about the limits of `readlines`. More generally, often you can say

```
n = length(A)::Int
```

when generic type inference fails but you can guarantee the type in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

As of 0.3.4:

```
julia> typeof(lines)
Array{Union(ASCIIString,UTF8String),1}
```

I just wanted to warn against:

```
convert(Array{ASCIIString,1}, lines)
```

that can fail (for non-ASCII) while I guess, in this case nothing needs to be done, this should work:

```
convert(Array{UTF8String,1}, lines)
```